# trycatch() logspline non-convergence

Tags: r, shiny

I have a matter which I couldn't solve for past couple of days. Which is:
I want to trycatch() when logspline is not converging. My part of the code which has to do that looks like this:

```
tryCatch({
pl1<-logspline(cost_disease,lbound=0,ubound=max(cost_disease), error.action=1)
pl2<-logspline(cost_disease1,lbound=0,ubound=max(cost_disease1), error.action=1)
dev.off()
}, 
error=function(e){cat("Logspline failed!",conditionMessage(e), "\n")})
```

I mention that I am using R shiny. And i still get this error :

```
Error in oldlogspline(x, lbound = jlx, ubound = jux) : * no convergence
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please add `dput(cost_disease1)` and `dput(cost_disease)` to your question.

Comment: Where exactly? I have added now the error that I get

Comment: Anywhere in your question - please take a few minutes to read through [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: After putting dput I get : [1] "simulation"
c(0, 4349.24946205504, 4702.17986997217, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4485.31364645809, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4465.72236994654, 0, 4489.17902391404, 
4015.13026135415, 3957.88117491826, 4415.88737084717, 0, 0)
c(477.103075448424, 0, 0, 230.54889459908, 217.801164692268, 
0, 3598.94042426348, 0, 0, 226.023693557829, 3247.3266235739, 
0, 0, 239.922602081671, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3171.49456971511, 219.66666730307, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 716.303983351216)
[1] "simulation"
Error in oldlogspline(x, lbound = jlx, ubound = jux) : * no convergence

Comment: @ilden he means that we need a sample of your two data sets in order to reproduce your code and errors and edit your question and copy/paste those in

Comment: @ilden There are multiple examples of how to use `dput` in the post that I linked, and please put the results in your *question*, not in a *comment*, as the former is much more visible.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for messy writing!